# Android: Implementing fragment issue (inflate exception)

Tags: android, android-fragments, inflate-exception

error: `02-18 10:10:24.260: E/AndroidRuntime(5769): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.opencv.samples.facedetect/activity.CameraTest}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class fragment`

Application with face detection camera.

- Have a user profile page with a button to test whether face detection camera is working
- When click on the button it opens **FaceDetectTest.class** which has the **test_activity.xml** which includes the **fdActivity.class** fragment.
- This has been done so I can have a tool bar at the top of the page to return to the previous screen, so I don't have to make loads of FdActivity classes

I have an application where face detection is used. Using open CV I have an fdActivity class which runs the face detection code. I have changed this from an activity to a fragment, so that I can re use it throughout code.

For instance I have a user profile page where they can click a button to see whether the face detection works. This opens an activity called TestActivity which view implements the fdActivity fragment to view the face detection camera & also have a toolbar at the top for returning to the previous page.

**test_detec_activity.xml which is used by TestActivity.class**
[image: test_detection_activity.xml]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bg_login"
    android:orientation="vertical" >       

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnReturnProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Profile" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headingText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnReturnProfile"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnReturnProfile"
        android:text="@string/faceDetetRequir" />

</RelativeLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"        
    class="openCV.facedetect.FdActivity" />
```

**TestActivity.class**

```
    package activity;

import org.opencv.samples.facedetect.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import helper.SessionManager;

public class CameraTest extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button btnReturnProfile;
    private SessionManager session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.test_detection_activity);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        setViewsFromLayout();
        setListenersFromLayout();

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btnReturnProfile){
            launchIntentToProfilePage();
            addCheckedCameraToSession();
            finish();
        }

    }
    private void addCheckedCameraToSession(){
        session.setCheckedCameraBeforeTest(true);
    }

    private void launchIntentToProfilePage(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserProfile.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void setViewsFromLayout(){
        btnReturnProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    }

    private void setListenersFromLayout(){
        btnReturnProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReturnProfile);
    }

}
```

**the fragment code:** (changed fdActivity of openCV)

```
    package openCV.facedetect;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;
import org.opencv.samples.facedetect.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class FdActivity extends Fragment implements CvCameraViewListener2 {

    private static final String    TAG                 = "OCVSample::Activity";
    private static final Scalar    FACE_RECT_COLOR     = new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 255);
    public static final int        JAVA_DETECTOR       = 0;
    public static final int        NATIVE_DETECTOR     = 1;

    private MenuItem               mItemFace50;
    private MenuItem               mItemFace40;
    private MenuItem               mItemFace30;
    private MenuItem               mItemFace20;
    private MenuItem               mItemType;

    private Mat                    mRgba;
    private Mat                    mGray;
    private File                   mCascadeFile;
    private CascadeClassifier      mJavaDetector;
    private DetectionBasedTracker  mNativeDetector;

    private int                    mDetectorType       = JAVA_DETECTOR;
    private String[]               mDetectorName;

    private float                  mRelativeFaceSize   = 0.2f;
    private int                    mAbsoluteFaceSize   = 0;

    private CameraBridgeViewBase   mOpenCvCameraView;

    private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(getActivity()) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
                System.loadLibrary("detection_based_tracker");

                try {
                    // load cascade file from application resources
                    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lbpcascade_frontalface);
                    File cascadeDir = getActivity().getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
                    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(mCascadeFile);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    is.close();
                    os.close();

                    mJavaDetector = new CascadeClassifier(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (mJavaDetector.empty()) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load cascade classifier");
                        mJavaDetector = null;
                    } else
                        Log.i(TAG, "Loaded cascade classifier from " + mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());

                    mNativeDetector = new DetectionBasedTracker(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath(), 0);

                    cascadeDir.delete();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load cascade. Exception thrown: " + e);
                }

                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
        }
    };

    public FdActivity() {
        mDetectorName = new String[2];
        mDetectorName[JAVA_DETECTOR] = "Java";
        mDetectorName[NATIVE_DETECTOR] = "Native (tracking)";

        Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.face_detect_surface_view, container, false);
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) getView().findViewById(R.id.fd_activity_surface_view);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCameraIndex(1);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, getActivity(), mLoaderCallback);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mGray = new Mat();
        mRgba = new Mat();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        mGray.release();
        mRgba.release();
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray = inputFrame.gray();

        if (mAbsoluteFaceSize == 0) {
            int height = mGray.rows();
            if (Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize) > 0) {
                mAbsoluteFaceSize = Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize);
            }
            mNativeDetector.setMinFaceSize(mAbsoluteFaceSize);
        }

        MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

        if (mDetectorType == JAVA_DETECTOR) {
            if (mJavaDetector != null)
                mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(mGray, faces, 1.1, 2, 2, // TODO: objdetect.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
                        new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize), new Size());
        }
        else if (mDetectorType == NATIVE_DETECTOR) {
            if (mNativeDetector != null)
                mNativeDetector.detect(mGray, faces);
        }
        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Detection method is not selected!");
        }

        Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++)
            Core.rectangle(mRgba, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), FACE_RECT_COLOR, 3);

        return mRgba;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onOptionsItemSelected; selected item: " + item);
        if (item == mItemFace50)
            setMinFaceSize(0.5f);
        else if (item == mItemFace40)
            setMinFaceSize(0.4f);
        else if (item == mItemFace30)
            setMinFaceSize(0.3f);
        else if (item == mItemFace20)
            setMinFaceSize(0.2f);
        else if (item == mItemType) {
            int tmpDetectorType = (mDetectorType + 1) % mDetectorName.length;
            item.setTitle(mDetectorName[tmpDetectorType]);
            setDetectorType(tmpDetectorType);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void setMinFaceSize(float faceSize) {
        mRelativeFaceSize = faceSize;
        mAbsoluteFaceSize = 0;
    }

    private void setDetectorType(int type) {
        if (mDetectorType != type) {
            mDetectorType = type;

            if (type == NATIVE_DETECTOR) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Detection Based Tracker enabled");
                mNativeDetector.start();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Cascade detector enabled");
                mNativeDetector.stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**face_detect_surface.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    android:id="@+id/fd_activity_surface_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

I'm new to using fragments, and I'm just looking for a way to reuse the fdActivity rather than make loads of different versions for different screens.

Thanks

**Edit stack trace**

```
    02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.opencv.samples.facedetect/activity.CameraActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class fragment
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2049)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2083)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1233)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class fragment
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:255)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1879)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at activity.CameraActivity.onCreate(CameraActivity.java:25)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4539)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2013)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     ... 11 more
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at openCV.facedetect.FaceDetectionFragment.onCreateView(FaceDetectionFragment.java:66)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:806)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1010)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1108)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4317)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
02-18 11:20:02.315: E/AndroidRuntime(7273):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: Please, share whole stack trace...

Comment: @GuilhermeP added for you

Comment: I have updated my CameraActivity class to include the call to open the fragments `Fragment fr = new FaceDetectionFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in `onCreate()` in your `CameraTest` activity.

Try to call `super.onCreate()` before `setContentView()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.test_detection_activity);

    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    setViewsFromLayout();
    setListenersFromLayout();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your setContentView() method for inflating the class.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_detection_activity);
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    setViewsFromLayout();
    setListenersFromLayout();
```

Also for using fragments you should use FrameLayout in your MainActivity. After that you can call fragments to that frame. Like:

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
>
```

After that on click of any widget call:

```
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new SampleFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```